# Amcharts pie tooltip position

Tags: javascript, plugins, charts, tooltip

Need to put a tooltip to the center of pie(donut) chart, and make a pointer point to the middle of each slice. Can't find much in documentation about tooltip positioning. Please, help.

Don't know if its needed, but here is a code of dataset:

```
chart.data = [
      {
        field: "Server & IT",
        result: 47,
        radius: 8,
        color: am4core.color("rgba(41, 133, 191, 1)"),
        icon: iconServer
      },
      {
        field: "Reisen",
        result: 28,
        radius: 7,
        color: am4core.color("rgba(55, 148, 207, 1)"),
        icon: iconServer
      }
]
```

And code of tooltip customization:

```
pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipHTML = `
      <div style="width: 140px; max-width: 140px; margin: 0 10px; margin-top: 50%; transform: translateY(-35%) rotate(45deg); overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="">
          <img src={icon} alt="">
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px 0;">{field}</div>
        <h2 style="font-weight: 400;">{percent}%</h2>
      <div> 
    `;
    pieSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
    pieSeries.tooltipPosition = "pointer";
    pieSeries.pointerAngle;
    pieSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("rgba(41, 133, 191, 1)");
    pieSeries.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 90;
    pieSeries.tooltip.background.strokeOpacity = 0;
    pieSeries.tool;
    pieSeries.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "horizontal";
    pieSeries.tooltip.tooltipPosition = "pointer";
    pieSeries.tooltip.label.width = 180;
    pieSeries.tooltip.label.height = 180;
```

*** UPD1. ***

[that's what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Pv7.png)

[that's what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ61V.png)

***S.O.S.***

Comment: Hello ! You should post a screenshot of what you have, and another (edited) of what you need. Because what you're going for is not clearly understandable from your description.

Comment: Hello, i added an images. Now tooltip follows cursor, and i need it to stay in the center of a chart, and make a pointer to point at the center of a hovered slice.